# On the matrix multiplication decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, matlab

I have matrix Multiplication of $H.Z.X = Y$ as mentioned below :

$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
h_{11} & \dots & h_{N 1} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
h_{N 1} & \cdots & h_{N N}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
Z_{11} & \cdots & Z_{N 1} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
Z_{N 1} & \cdots & Z_{N N}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
X_{1} \\
\cdot \\
x_{N}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}
Y_{1} \\
\cdot \\
y_{N}
\end{array}\right]$

The size of matrix $H$ and $Z$ is $(256,256)$ and size of vectors $X$ and $Y$ is $(256,1)$. What I know about matrix $Z$ is permutation matrix where the $32$ first rows are zeros except columns $1,9,17,...(265-8)$. Similarly, next $32$ rows are zeros except columns $2,10,18,...(256-7)$. The next $32$ rows are zeros except columns $3,11,19,...(256-6)$ till the last $32$ rows which are zeros except $8,16,24,...256$.

My question, is it possible to simplify the matrix multiplication by specifying the required part of matrix $H$ to be multiplied with non-zeros values of $Z$? I mean for example get the part of $H_{32,32}$ and multiply it with $Z_{32,32}$ to then multiply it with first $32$ elements of $X_{1:32}$ to be equaled  the first $32$ first element of $Y_{1:32}$ and so on.
I mean to avoid the large multiplications of elements with zeros values of matrix $Z$ at the same time to have less complexity in multiplications.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to work out $ZX$ first as you don't need matrix multiplication, just permute the $x_i$ in the way you've indicated?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I prefer working out $HZ$ since the scenario I work on it supposes that $X$ is unknown and I must estimate it.

Comment: Thanks. But surely if you can estimate $ZX$ you can estimate $X$ by a trivial permutation?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you so much .. but in that way, estimating $ZH$ will increase the complexity computation. so what I need is to decompose $HZ$ into small matrices of $32x32$  and then applying compressive sensing into $y$ with resulted matrix in order to estimate $X$. By the way, $X$ is sparse

Comment: You should mention your previous questions such as (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3580612) in order to explain why you are interested into these "shuffles", that otherwise one doesn't understand....